# Update a mesh VBO

Tags: c++, opengl, bullet

I got a soft body simulation running with the bullet physics engine, thus I have to update the mesh vertices' position each frame. To do so I use the following function :

```
void Mesh::update_VBO(std::vector<Vertex> const & updated_vertices)
{
    indices.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < updated_vertices.size(); i++)
    {
        indices.push_back(i);
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);

    void * VBO_ptr = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
    void * EBO_ptr = glMapBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
    memcpy(VBO_ptr, updated_vertices.data(), updated_vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex));
    memcpy(EBO_ptr, indices.data(), indices.size() * sizeof(int));

    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);

    vertices.clear();
    vertices = updated_vertices;
}
```

Now, the problem is that sometimes I got a segmentation fault, and sometimes it runs without errors.
I'm sure the issue comes from that function because when I replace the above code by the following one, all of a sudden, no errors, everything runs well (the only drawback with the **recreate** function that i call instead, is that it induces some really bad performances because I delete the former VAO and create a new set of VAO VBO and EBO):

```
void Mesh::update_VBO(std::vector<Vertex> const & updated_vertices)
{
    indices.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < updated_vertices.size(); i++)
    {
        indices.push_back(i);
    }
    recreate(updated_vertices, indices);
/*
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);

    void * VBO_ptr = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
    void * EBO_ptr = glMapBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
    memcpy(VBO_ptr, updated_vertices.data(), updated_vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex));
    memcpy(EBO_ptr, indices.data(), indices.size() * sizeof(int));

    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);

    vertices.clear();
    vertices = updated_vertices;
*/
}
```

One more thing is that the **update_VBO** function was a function I did for a simpler program with two cubes linked by a rope, the whole thing falling on the ground, and everything worked fine for that small program.

[image: cubes and rope soft body]

But now that I merged that function into my main project, it fails.

What am I missing?

EDIT :
here is the code that fixed my problem as stated in the comment section below

```
// recreate cable left mesh
        prev_c_left_vertices = init_previous_vertices(vertices, fixed_left_vertices);
        g->pod->cable_left->get_mesh_collection().at(0)->recreate(prev_c_left_vertices, fixed_left_indices);
```

```
// recreate cable right mesh
        prev_c_right_vertices = init_previous_vertices(vertices, fixed_right_vertices);
        g->pod->cable_right->get_mesh_collection().at(0)->recreate(prev_c_right_vertices, fixed_right_indices);
```

And here is the full code where I create the soft bodies :

```
    // ----------********** CABLES CREATION
    // step simulation
    dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(1.0f/60.0f, 10);

    // chariot model
    btTransform transform_chariot;
    if(chariot_body && chariot_body->getMotionState())
        chariot_body->getMotionState()->getWorldTransform(transform_chariot);
    transform_chariot.getOpenGLMatrix(glm::value_ptr(chariot_model));

    // -----***** create cable left soft body
    Mesh* cable_left_mesh = g->pod->cable_left->get_mesh_collection().at(0);
    // get rid of duplicated vertices
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices = cable_left_mesh->get_vertex_list();
        for(int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
        {
            glm::vec3 before = vertices.at(i).position;
            glm::vec4 before2(before.x, before.y, before.z, 1.0f);
            glm::vec4 after = chariot_model * glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -0.02f, 0.3f)) * before2;
            vertices.at(i).position = glm::vec3(after.x, after.y, after.z);
        }
        std::vector<int> indices = cable_left_mesh->get_index_list();

        std::vector<Vertex> fixed_left_vertices;
        std::vector<int> fixed_left_indices;

        std::vector<std::pair<glm::vec3, int>> couple;

        for(int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i += 3) // for each face
        {
            // get the 3 couples of the current face
            glm::vec3 a_pos = vertices.at(indices.at(i)).position;
            int a_index = indices.at(i);

            glm::vec3 b_pos = vertices.at(indices.at(i+1)).position;
            int b_index = indices.at(i+1);

            glm::vec3 c_pos = vertices.at(indices.at(i+2)).position;
            int c_index = indices.at(i+2);

            // check for each couple if its position is already defined by another couple in the clean array
            int a_def_index = get_vertex_defined_index(a_pos, a_index, couple);
            int b_def_index = get_vertex_defined_index(b_pos, b_index, couple);
            int c_def_index = get_vertex_defined_index(c_pos, c_index, couple);

            if(a_def_index == -1)
                couple.push_back(std::make_pair(a_pos, a_index));
            if(b_def_index == -1)
                couple.push_back(std::make_pair(b_pos, b_index));
            if(c_def_index == -1)
                couple.push_back(std::make_pair(c_pos, c_index));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < couple.size(); i++)
        {
            int couple_index = couple.at(i).second;
            fixed_left_vertices.push_back(vertices.at(couple_index));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i += 3)
        {
            glm::vec3 a_pos = vertices.at(indices.at(i)).position;
            glm::vec3 b_pos = vertices.at(indices.at(i+1)).position;
            glm::vec3 c_pos = vertices.at(indices.at(i+2)).position;

            fixed_left_indices.push_back(retrieve_correct_index(a_pos, couple));
            fixed_left_indices.push_back(retrieve_correct_index(b_pos, couple));
            fixed_left_indices.push_back(retrieve_correct_index(c_pos, couple));
        }

        // create left soft body
        cable_left = btSoftBodyHelpers::CreateFromTriMesh(*softBody_worldInfo, vertex_list_2_btScalarArray(fixed_left_vertices), fixed_left_indices.data(), fixed_left_indices.size() / 3);

        // create left soft body material
        btSoftBody::Material* left_material = cable_left->appendMaterial();
        left_material->m_kLST = 0.75f;
        left_material->m_kAST = 0.0f;
        left_material->m_kVST = 1.0f;

        cable_left->generateBendingConstraints(5, left_material);
        cable_left->generateClusters(32);
        cable_left->setPose(true, false);
        cable_left->setTotalMass(0.65f, true);
        cable_left->m_cfg.piterations = 10;
        cable_left->randomizeConstraints();

        // add left soft body to the dynamics world
        dynamicsWorld->addSoftBody(cable_left);
        initial_c_left_vertices = fixed_left_vertices;
        prev_c_left_vertices = fixed_left_vertices;

        // attach left soft body to chariot and reactors
        btSoftBody::tNodeArray left_nodes = cable_left->m_nodes;

        std::qsort(fixed_left_vertices.data(), fixed_left_vertices.size(), sizeof(Vertex), cmp_vertex);

        for(int i = 0; i < left_nodes.size(); i++)
        {
            btVector3 pos = left_nodes.at(i).m_x;
            for(int j = 0; j < 21; j++)
            {
                glm::vec3 v_pos = fixed_left_vertices.at(j).position;
                if(pos.x() == v_pos.x && pos.y() == v_pos.y && pos.z() && v_pos.z)
                {
                    cable_left->appendAnchor(i, chariot_body);
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < left_nodes.size(); i++)
        {
            btVector3 pos = left_nodes.at(i).m_x;
            for(int j = fixed_left_vertices.size() - 1; j > fixed_left_vertices.size() - 22; j--)
            {
                glm::vec3 v_pos = fixed_left_vertices.at(j).position;
                if(pos.x() == v_pos.x && pos.y() == v_pos.y && pos.z() && v_pos.z)
                {
                    cable_left->appendAnchor(i, reactors_body);
                }
            }
        }

        // recreate cable left mesh
        prev_c_left_vertices = init_previous_vertices(vertices, fixed_left_vertices);
        g->pod->cable_left->get_mesh_collection().at(0)->recreate(prev_c_left_vertices, fixed_left_indices);

        // -----***** create cable right soft body
        Mesh* cable_right_mesh = g->pod->cable_right->get_mesh_collection().at(0);
        // get rid of duplicated vertices
        vertices.clear(); indices.clear();
        vertices = cable_right_mesh->get_vertex_list();
        for(int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
        {
            glm::vec3 before = vertices.at(i).position;
            glm::vec4 before2(before.x, before.y, before.z, 1.0f);
            glm::vec4 after = chariot_model * glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -0.02f, 0.3f)) * before2;
            vertices.at(i).position = glm::vec3(after.x, after.y, after.z);
        }
        indices = cable_right_mesh->get_index_list();

        std::vector<Vertex> fixed_right_vertices;
        std::vector<int> fixed_right_indices;

        couple.clear();

        for(int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i += 3) // for each face
        {
            // get the 3 couples of the current face
            glm::vec3 a_pos = vertices.at(indices.at(i)).position;
            int a_index = indices.at(i);

            glm::vec3 b_pos = vertices.at(indices.at(i+1)).position;
            int b_index = indices.at(i+1);

            glm::vec3 c_pos = vertices.at(indices.at(i+2)).position;
            int c_index = indices.at(i+2);

            // check for each couple if its position is already defined by another couple in the clean array
            int a_def_index = get_vertex_defined_index(a_pos, a_index, couple);
            int b_def_index = get_vertex_defined_index(b_pos, b_index, couple);
            int c_def_index = get_vertex_defined_index(c_pos, c_index, couple);

            if(a_def_index == -1)
                couple.push_back(std::make_pair(a_pos, a_index));
            if(b_def_index == -1)
                couple.push_back(std::make_pair(b_pos, b_index));
            if(c_def_index == -1)
                couple.push_back(std::make_pair(c_pos, c_index));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < couple.size(); i++)
        {
            int couple_index = couple.at(i).second;
            fixed_right_vertices.push_back(vertices.at(couple_index));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i += 3)
        {
            glm::vec3 a_pos = vertices.at(indices.at(i)).position;
            glm::vec3 b_pos = vertices.at(indices.at(i+1)).position;
            glm::vec3 c_pos = vertices.at(indices.at(i+2)).position;

            fixed_right_indices.push_back(retrieve_correct_index(a_pos, couple));
            fixed_right_indices.push_back(retrieve_correct_index(b_pos, couple));
            fixed_right_indices.push_back(retrieve_correct_index(c_pos, couple));
        }

        // create right soft body
        cable_right = btSoftBodyHelpers::CreateFromTriMesh(*softBody_worldInfo, vertex_list_2_btScalarArray(fixed_right_vertices), fixed_right_indices.data(), fixed_right_indices.size() / 3);

        // create right soft body material
        btSoftBody::Material* right_material = cable_right->appendMaterial();
        right_material->m_kLST = 0.75f;
        right_material->m_kAST = 0.0f;
        right_material->m_kVST = 1.0f;

        cable_right->generateBendingConstraints(5, right_material); // 2
        cable_right->generateClusters(32);
        cable_right->setPose(true, false);
        cable_right->setTotalMass(0.65f, true);
        cable_right->m_cfg.piterations = 10;
        cable_right->randomizeConstraints();

        // add right soft body to the dynamics world
        dynamicsWorld->addSoftBody(cable_right);
        initial_c_right_vertices = fixed_right_vertices;
        prev_c_right_vertices = fixed_right_vertices;

        // attach right soft body to chariot and reactors
        btSoftBody::tNodeArray right_nodes = cable_right->m_nodes;

        std::qsort(fixed_right_vertices.data(), fixed_right_vertices.size(), sizeof(Vertex), cmp_vertex);

        for(int i = 0; i < right_nodes.size(); i++)
        {
            btVector3 pos = right_nodes.at(i).m_x;
            for(int j = 0; j < 21; j++)
            {
                glm::vec3 v_pos = fixed_right_vertices.at(j).position;
                if(pos.x() == v_pos.x && pos.y() == v_pos.y && pos.z() && v_pos.z)
                {
                    cable_right->appendAnchor(i, chariot_body);
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < right_nodes.size(); i++)
        {
            btVector3 pos = right_nodes.at(i).m_x;
            for(int j = fixed_right_vertices.size() - 1; j > fixed_right_vertices.size() - 22; j--)
            {
                glm::vec3 v_pos = fixed_right_vertices.at(j).position;
                if(pos.x() == v_pos.x && pos.y() == v_pos.y && pos.z() && v_pos.z)
                {
                    cable_right->appendAnchor(i, reactors_body);
                }
            }
        }

        // recreate cable right mesh
        prev_c_right_vertices = init_previous_vertices(vertices, fixed_right_vertices);
        g->pod->cable_right->get_mesh_collection().at(0)->recreate(prev_c_right_vertices, fixed_right_indices);
```

Comment: I tried and I still get a segmentation fault, thanks for the fast answer though !

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to push more vertices in your buffer than you allocated space for. You can update a buffer at will only as long as it's the same size, if you want to increase the number of vertices you have to reallocate it.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that when I did my program with the two cubes, because I had a segfault caused by that issue, so I multiplied the initial buffer size by 100 to prevent this.
So I guess that's not the issue here, because I also used that trick in the other failing program.

Comment: "I guess" -- that worries me, is it a problem or is it not? Is the error you're seeing an access violation on one of the `memcpy`? Look at the variables that hold the size of the data you're copying, do they make sense? Are they less than the size you allocated for the buffer or not?

Comment: Also if your indices are just sequential from 0, you're wasting performance, not gaining anything from it. Just don't use an index buffer.

Comment: Well thank you, you gave me a hint, I inserted some print for the VBO size, and one print isn't called, the print that are called are in the update_VBO function, the other ones are in the recreate function. The bullet physics engine creates a soft body mesh full of duplicated vertices, so after I used the constructor to load the obj mesh, I then have to remove all duplicated vertices made by the soft body creation, that's why I then call the recreate function which produces a clean mesh, and then for each frame, I call the update_VBO.

Comment: I come back soon !

Comment: Ok, I haven't called the recreate function in my class that manages the soft bodies, maybe I'm on it !

Comment: Alright now it is working :D Sorry I am really stupid !
I indeed just forgot to call recreate in my WorldPhysics class, I'm going to edit my post with the fix !

Comment: Thank you Blindy !